# How do I get 'one-of' Nod Validation to work with checkboxes?

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I'm having an issue with this plugin trying to validate checkboxes.

In the list of metrics there is a metric called 'one-of' which works for radio button validation, but I can't seem to get it to work with checkboxes. I have 5 checkboxes and want the user to select at least one. Any ideas?

This is the plugin:
http://casperin.github.io/nod/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that checkbox validation was overlooked and will be included in the rewrite of this plugin. However, I did manage a simple fix which can be viewed here:

https://github.com/casperin/nod/issues/56